# PCI Idle Session Timeout general question

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope

Can someone help me understand how the PCI Timeout rules change for an application like the Starbucks App? A user is able to keep their card open ready for scan for longer the 15 minutes if needed, but PCI A11y AA also requires to display a message giving the user a chance to react and keep the session alive.

I understand and have implemented it from an e-commerce approach but am a bit confused on the e-wallet approach.

Comment: Which document are you referencing?  They have a lot of documentation on various things, and I'm not sure which one you're referring to.  It's quite possible that the difference is that the _cardholder_ isn't subject to any PCI requirements, so an app they use doesn't have to deal with that.  But without knowing the specific document/rule, I can't confirm that.